# How do I embed a ViewController into a UIView programatically in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController containing a UIView, and I want to embed a second ViewController programatically into the UIView. I'd presumed I needed to use `.addSubview()`, but it will not accept a UIViewController type.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You don't add UIViewControllers to UIViews, instead you add UIViews to UIViewControllers.

Comment: You need addChildViewController method from UIViewController class https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchildviewcontroller

Comment: Try a `Container View` that should meet your needs, because a container view links you to a new viewController. Then create a reference to the containerView and add it the your views subView

Answer (score 0):

.addSubview() takes a UIView type as its parameter. UIViewController is not a UIView. You can add your view controller's view like this:

```
myView.addSubview(myViewController.view)
```

But this will prevent all the UIViewController methods from working properly, i.e. viewDidAppear will not be called. If you want to do it properly, you should implement a [container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).